# AVAudioPlayer with two definition in the same if

Tags: ios, if-statement, avaudioplayer

I want to to fore one action only if there is two exacting cases, i try to use a variable if and else, but never result:

**This is what i try**

```
    if (loop_ == NO || [myPlayer isPlaying]) {

        [myPlayer stop];
    }
```

I want says if myLoop is OFF and myPlayer `isPlayng`, stop myPlayer, in other case do nothing.

I trying with || and && but not work, maybe i take a bad vote because i know is very simple, but i don't remember how can do that.

Thanks

Comment: is a BOOL for check if LoopSound is ON of OFF

Comment: `if (loop_ && [myPlayer isPlaying]) {` This will stop the play if `loop_` is true and the player is playing.

Comment: @Jhon why don't you make life easier on yourself and break this into two if-else. i.e. Top if check if loop_ is true then check if player is playing. otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: Good, but i write wrong sorry want to stop if loop_ is NULL

Comment: no because i have a groovebox and if you continue tap the player have to do continue stop and play, but if you tap on loop and become enable when you tap on button, the player continue with infinite loop, but if you disable the loop and tap on button isPlaying i need to the stop immediate

Comment: @Jhon `loop_` is a `BOOL`. It can't ever be `NULL`. It's either `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: @maddy yeah sorry ( to many think in my head :) ) so but how can do duble check 'if (loop_ = NO and [myPlayer isPlaying] )' stop audio?